# Supporting range requests using Rocket

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I know Rocket has support for [the `Accept-Ranges` header](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/http/hyper/header/struct.AcceptRanges.html), but how would I implement a `Responder` that properly handles [a `Range` header](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/http/hyper/header/enum.Range.html)?

I found [a version that had some preliminary support](https://gitlab.com/dannypsnl/Rocket-rs/blob/0d3684b55989d6e6b24e00618546da77f917a0a6/lib/src/response/responder.rs#L235) for having the `Responder` implementation for `File` handle a `Range` header, but it seems to [no longer be present](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/blob/master/core/lib/src/response/responder.rs#L243-L251).

Comment: There seems to be a pending pull request for that: [#887](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/pull/887).

Comment: Thanks! I missed that in my searches. It looks like I will have to implement this behaviour myself for now, sadly.